# Why does HTML5 video autoplay when half in viewport, when threshold is set to 1, using IntersectionObserver?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, intersection-observer

Using this code to autoplay a series of videos, depending on if they are in the viewport:

```
/**AUTOPLAY VIDEO IN VIEWPORT**/

function playPauseVideo() {
    let videos = document.querySelectorAll("video");
    videos.forEach((video) => {
        // We can only control playback without insteraction if video is mute
        video.muted = true;
        // Play is a promise so we need to check we have it
        let playPromise = video.play();
        if (playPromise !== undefined) {
            playPromise.then((_) => {
                let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
                    (entries) => {
                        entries.forEach((entry) => {
                            if (
                                entry.intersectionRatio !== 1 &&
                                !video.paused
                            ) {
                                video.pause();
                            } else if (video.paused) {
                                /*setTimeout(function() {
                                  video.play();
                                }, 5000);*/
                                video.play();
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    { threshold: 1}
                );
                observer.observe(video);
            });
        }
    });
}

// And you would kick this off where appropriate with:
playPauseVideo();
```

I'm trying to understand why, when I scroll the video into view it plays as expected, but if the video is finished and I begin to scroll further the video will start again even if it is only partly in the viewport.  I want the video(s) to stay paused/stopped until it is completely back into the viewport.  The threshold for IntersectionObserver is set to 1 - so this behaviour is confusing me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making it too complicated. you don't need to check `audio.play()` as it will play the videos unnecessarily.

here is how I would code it:

```js
function handleIntersection(entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const video = entry.target;

    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      video.play();
    } else {
      video.pause();
    }
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection, {
  threshold: 1.0
});

const videos = document.querySelectorAll('.video');

videos.forEach(video => {
  observer.observe(video);
});
```

Comment: Great.  This is much leaner and works perfectly.  Thanks for your input Arash.